# IONIC Click Event. Not Working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The Code Below Works Perfectly fine when i run it in browser. But when the same code is placed in ionic specific code. it doesn't
Can you guys help me through it.
Thanks in Advace.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="empcontroller">
<form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="empno">
       <input type="text" ng-model="empname"> 
        <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="insertdata()" /> 
</form>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
    app.controller('empcontroller',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.insertdata=function(){
            $http.post("localhost/Angular/insert.php",{
                'empno' : $scope.empno, 'empname' : $scope.empname
            }).sucess(function(data,status,headers,config)
            {
                console.log("Data inserted Sucessfully");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The Pic Will Give a Little Bit more Explanation
[image: The Click Event Doesn't Occur]

[image: Whereas This Does]

Comment: Why don't you use Ionic tags there?

Comment: I tired @GSURENDARTHINA But the Result was same.
if you could guide me with the same it would be really helpful.

Comment: spell check on success function, there's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML Code can be as follows.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="empcontroller">
    <ion-input type="text" ng-model="empno"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" ng-model="empname"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block ng-click="insertdata()">Submit</button></ion-input>
</div>
```

The above is in `AngularJS`. If you want to use `Angular2`, then follow the below code.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="empcontroller">
  <form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="empno"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="empname"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block (click)="insertdata()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Moreover, I would suggest you to write your codes in the respective files. That is, your HTML code into the `.html` and SCRIPT code into the `.ts` or `.js` file.

Also, working on browser is different than working on an Android Build.

Comment: Thanks a ton Bro!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recommended DI style otherwise problems will happen in minificaiton of js, and angularjs won't find dependencies.

```
app.controller('empcontroller', ['$scope', '$http' ,function($scope,$http){

}]);
```

Comment: This Code Works Perfectly When i run it from a browser. but it doesn't when i bundle the code with ionic